# How to use alter in sql syntax error[MYSQL]

Tags: mysql, sql, alter

I need to modify a table that it already exists. The start table is this:

```
create TABLE schema.students(
  id_students int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  data_signUP date NOT NULL,
  description varchar(100) CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_bin NOT NULL,
  id_university int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id_students),
  KEY id_university(id_university),
  CONSTRAINT students_university_FK FOREIGN KEY (id_university) REFERENCES university(id_university)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 COLLATE=latin1_general_ci;
```

Now  i need modify table and add another FK in the table exams(id_exam), I need to modify also colum "description" that first was not null but now can  be null so i do:

```
 alter TABLE schema.students(
      id_students int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
      data_signUP date NOT NULL,
      add description varchar(100) CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_bin DEFAULT NULL,
      id_university int(11) NOT NULL,
 id_exam int(11) NOT NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY (id_students),
      KEY id_university(id_university),
 ADD KEY id_exam(id_exam),
      CONSTRAINT students_university_FK FOREIGN KEY (id_university) REFERENCES university(id_university),
CONSTRAINT students_exams_FK FOREIGN KEY (id_exam) REFERENCES exams(id_exam)
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 COLLATE=latin1_general_ci;
```

Anyone can help me?

Comment: What is the problem? What error you have?

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/alter-table-examples.html

Answer (score 0):

You can recreate the entire schema by dropping the table and recreating it.

Otherwise, look at the [`ALTER TABLE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/alter-table.html) syntax.  You can do things like:

```
alter table students modify column description varchar(100);
```

You can do something similar for the foreign key constraint.